# Xml values from URL in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Below, xml file at "http://example.com/example.xml"

```
<xml>

<result>
    <name>abc name</name>                       
    <first>568</first>
    <second>458</second>
    <third>185</third>
    <forth>236</forth>
    <last>974</last>
</result>

<result>
    <name>def name</name>                       
    <first>214</first>
    <second>456</second>
    <third>457</third>
    <forth>754</forth>
    <last>746</last>
</result>

</xml>
```

i want get first, second, third, forth and last value for abc name. how i get values from xml URL?

Comment: For extracting them from that text (you don't need the url any more if you have already the xml text) you can use an xml parser or write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links provide some example and detail:

http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/
http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using DOM parser.
You should try using DOM parser.

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(“result”);

System.out.println("----------------------------");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        if( eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent().equals(“abc”))
        {
           System.out.println(“first” + eElement.getElementsByTagName(“first”).item(0).getTextContent());
           System.out.println(“second” + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
          //And so on           
         }

    }
}
```